# Как вернуть ответ ajax запроса в переменную?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Реализую метод, он принимает путь в каталоге, делает запрос на сервер, передавая путь, сервер возвращает id.

Полученный ответ находится в другой области видимости и не могу положить егь в переменную которая ожидает ответа от вызова функции.

Ведь на момент присовения значения переменной отвте ещё не пришёл.

Как можно поступить в подобной ситуации?

```js
var id = getId(relativePath);

function getId(relativePath) {

  var jqxhr = $.get("http://192.168.1.1:8080/ContentFileId", {
    "relativePath": relativePath
  }, null, "text");

  return jqxhr.always(function(response) {

    if (typeof response == 'string') {

      return response;

    } else {

      console.log(response.responseText);

    }

  })
}
```

Comment: Не так давно был похожий вопрос. Как вариант, можно передать через callback функцию, которая должна работать с полученным id

Comment: имете ввиду вторымм параметром при вызове callback передавать?

Comment: Да, либо так, либо через [promise](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/). Посмотрите ответы дубликата.